# How to apply a function iteratively over a single dataframe in R?

Tags: r, reduce, purrr

I'm trying to turn this operation into a function where I could set the `n` argument and without using `for loop`. This example is for 3 times. I thought I could do it with `purrr::reduce` but it needs a list (?).

```
tibble::add_row(tibble::add_row(tibble::add_row(df, .before = 1), .before = 1), .before = 1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
reduce(rep(list(add_row), 3), ~.y(.x, .before = 1), .init =df)

   x  y
1 NA NA
2 NA NA
3 NA NA
4  1  3
5  2  4
```

Answer (score 1):

```r
library(tidyverse)

add_row_n <- function(df, n) {
  walk(1:n, ~ {df <<- add_row(df, .before = 1)})
  df
}

tibble() %>% 
  add_row_n(3)
#> # A tibble: 3 × 0

tibble(x = 1, y = 2) %>% 
  add_row_n(3)
#> # A tibble: 4 × 2
#>       x     y
#>   <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1    NA    NA
#> 2    NA    NA
#> 3    NA    NA
#> 4     1     2
```

<sup>Created on 2021-11-26 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
add_n_rows = function(df, n) {
    
    new.rows = as.data.frame(matrix(NA, nrow=n, ncol=ncol(df)))
    colnames(new.rows) <- colnames(df)
    
    df %>% add_row(new.rows, .before = 1)        
}

# test
df = data.frame(x = rnorm(10), y = rnorm(10))
add_n_rows(df, 3)
```